# Apps script : trying to concatenate 2 string arrays has no effect (one pass writing values and count of values)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, concatenation, push

I'm reading a range of values and trying to copy them onto another range + the count of non empty cells.
I have the count value pushed to each row array.
However I want to add (push) 2 empty cells to each row before pushing the count value.

For consistency with other operations, I need to do the copying (values plus count) in one pass.
I can't add the empty cells to each row after trying concat, split/join or push

Here's a sheet explaining the problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IpABynmA5hd4PW9YqK6S5Gn1Gmw3GGEvBqsVadXiYkA/edit?usp=sharing

```
function testInsertValues() {
    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A5:G10").getValues()
  
  var fillArray = ["",""] // meant to be concatenated to each row
  
  var data = values.filter(r => {
    r.push([...r].filter(c => c !=="").length - 1) 
    r.concat(fillArray) // => no effect ??
    Logger.log("r : " + JSON.stringify(r) )  
    return r
  }).filter(r => r[r.length - 1 ] )  // not counting the first column
  
  Logger.log("data : " + JSON.stringify(data) + "  "  + data.length +"\n")  
  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(5,10,data.length,data[0].length);
  destinationRange.setValues(data);    
}
```

Comment: `r.push(...fillArray)`

Comment: I forgot about the spread operator ! 
Thank you !